# Error Connecting To SQL using VBA Code Without Using Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I am trying to connect to a SQL via VBA Code on Excel.

The problem is that when I am logged in on my username, I can connect to the database without problem. But when I try to connect with other user logged in, the connection is unsucessful.

I have already created a user inside my Database, like the picture below:

[image: User Created on Database]

And my connection on VBA is being done this way:

```
Option Explicit

Public DB As New ADODB.Connection
Public RST As New ADODB.Recordset
Public caminho, strConn As String
Public Msg As String

Sub CONECTA_DB()

strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=BR1104053\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
          "Initial Catalog=BDVestiario;" & _
          "Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
          "User ID=bdvestiario;" & _
          "Password=#infra#sudeste#;"


Set DB = New ADODB.Connection
Set RST = New ADODB.Recordset

DB.Open strConn

RST.CursorLocation = adUseClient
```

This gives a connection error when logged on other user, but connects normally when I am loggen on my user.

The problem, is that I need all my company to use this excel sheet connecting to SQL, so I need a common username to read and write on the database.

Comment: It probably doesn't really matter in *this* case (or does it?), but I'd strongly recommend you redact passwords/credentials when you post anything online. Feel free to [edit] it out, and note you can flag it for moderator attention, to get the revision history redacted, if you need to (same with the answer you got)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set Integrated Security to false or removed completely from your connection string.  When this is true or SSIS Windows credentials are used.

```
strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=BR1104053\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
      "Initial Catalog=BDVestiario;" & _
      "User ID=bdvestiario;" & _
      "Password=#infra#sudeste#;"
```

Comment: I have tried this, but still have no success. I received a failed logon message with the 'bdvestiario' user when I try this. Maybe I'm creating the user on the wrong way on SQL Server? @jradich1234

Comment: I just noticed that you're using SQL Express.  Have you configured the SQL Express server to allow remote connections?  It does not allow them by default.  Here's a [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2005/05/05/how-to-configure-express-to-accept-remote-connections/) on how to enable remote connections.

Comment: thanks @jradich1234...I have already done this too...but I discovered the problem. I didn't restart the server after created the new logon. After the restart it worked perfectly! Thanks!